# running boolean method from main

Tags: java, boolean

I'm trying to compare two integers or double parameters by using the method from main.
I don't understand what the problem is.
The parameters `bitterChocolate_amount` and `milkChocolate_amount`
are defined as integers.

Main:

```
boolean x = equals(bitterChocolate_amount,milkChocolate_amount)
```

Method:

```
public boolean equals (Fat other)
{
    if (this == other) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The error message is

```
  required: Object
  found: int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Comment: What's the overall task you're trying to solve? I can see a class called `Fat` and two kinds of chocolate, so there's clearly more going on here than comparing two numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This `public boolean equals (Fat other)` is your method accept only one argument. But `boolean x = equals(bitterChocolate_amount,milkChocolate_amount)` in this you passing two argument.

Do like this

```
boolean x = equals(bitterChocolate_amount,milkChocolate_amount);
```

Method:

```
public boolean equals (int bitterChocolate, int milkChocolate)
{
      if (bitterChocolate == milkChocolate)
           return true;
       else 
           return false;
}
```

Comment: Or simply `return bitterChocolate == milkChocolate`

Answer (score 0):

This `public boolean equals (Fat other)` method accepts only one argument but you are passing 2 arguments here `equals(bitterChocolate_amount,milkChocolate_amount)` Also as you said to compare 2 integers then the method will be like this

```
public boolean equals (int other,int someother)
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your `actual` and `formal` parameters doesn't match
 you can edit your method like this.

```
 boolean x = equals(bitterChocolate_amount,milkChocolate_amount)
```

Method:

```
public boolean equals (int value1,int value2)
{

      if (value1 == value2)
       {
           return true;
       }
       else 
       {
           return false;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need for an "equals" method. Simply use operators like:

```
if(int_a == int_b) { // returns true or false
    //my code...
}
```

Take a look: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned above, you're trying to pass two arguments (bitterChocolate_amount,milkChocolate_amount) to a method with only one available parameter (Fat other).

Not to mention the parameter type (Fat) is different to the arguments you're trying to pass in (int, int).

I can't really tell from the scope of the code you provided, but since you're calling that from a main class without any mention of an object instance you probably want to be declaring the method as static too.

This is bread and butter stuff here, I think you should be left alone to figure it out yourself as you'll learn a heck of a lot more that way. I'd recommend a good book if you're interested in long term investment; Head First books and Deitel and Deitel are pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

You call method with one parameter and use two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self-explanatory
required: Object
  found: int,int

The way you defined your equals method, it expects one parameter of type "Fat".
I assume you must have created the Fat class.

Now you are calling this method using two integer parameters, that's why its saying

required :object (of type "Fat")
 and found: int, int

Now lets focus on your requirement

1. If you just want to compare two integer values, modify your equals method to the one defined below

   ```
   public boolean equals (int value1,int value2)
   {

   if (value1 == value2)
   {
      return true;
   }
   else 
   {
      return false;
   }
   }
   ```
2. In your equals method, you have used "this", which means you should call it on an object.
   So it should be like this

   ```
   Fat f = new Fat(3);
   Fat g = new Fat(4);
   f.equals(g)
   ```

   But in this case, as you are comparing objects, (this==other) will not work as both the objects are different. == compares the object themselves and not the value they are storing. SO I am not sure what you want to achieve.

It will be better to get the right answer if you clarify your requirements.